# Local Variable Initialization Java

Tags: java

```
public class LocalVariables {

    static public void main(String args[]){

        int var;

        if(args.length > 0){
            var = 10;

        }

        else{
            var = 20;
        }
        System.out.println(var);
    }

}
```

Here if I remove `else` part it's showing compilation error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The local variable var may not have been initialized
```

Explain how the local variable value is initialized if I use `else` part.

Comment: shouldn't this be `public static void main` and not `static public void main`?

Comment: @px06 literally no difference. You can declare the modifiers in whatever order you like.

Comment: Well, without the else, what would be the value of `var` when `args.length != 10`? Where do you think that value comes from?

Comment: @AndyTurner right okay, other than that I don't see a problem with it

Comment: If you remove the `else` clause then `var` might not be assigned any value before you try and print it out. Pretty clear error message. What part is giving you difficulty?

Comment: @px06 read the question. OP says there's a problem if he removes the `else`.

Comment: You must do some SO search before posting questions!!

Comment: How ELSE part is ensuring initialization of variable? There's no problem with IF condition but if I remove ELSE it's throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it like this *what happens when the `if` condition in your code is not met?* The reason you would be getting an error saying :

> The local variable **var** may not have been initialized

is because if the condition is `false` you really don't have `var` initialised, do you?

On the other hand `else` was serving the purpose of ensuring the initialization in the existing code for you.

Comment: When the condition of IF is not met the output is 20 . Tell me how else part is ensuring initialization why not  if part?

Comment: once you remove `else` part and your args.length `< =0`. Could you tell me what would be the value of `var` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

if you remove else block, what would be the value of `var` `if(args.length<0)` ? The compiler doesn't know that. So it shows you error. Either you have to initialize the `var` during declaration or you need to initialize in both if and else block.

Comment: `if (args.length <= 0)`.

Answer (score -1):

When executing `main` method, surely you do not provide `args` argument. So `args.length > 0` returns false.

Comment: did you try running the code?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with OP's problem. OP is asking about a compilation problem, not a runtime problem.